# Parsing result of inner join in java [Performance Related]

Tags: java, mysql

So I am currently in an issue regarding joins. I have 4 tables that I "left join" together.
My Question here is the following:
If I select all the rows from the resulting join how will I be able to parse the information into java code?

For the sake of an example let's say we have the following table:

```
Persons
ID | NAME
1 | Tim
2 | Matthew
```

And

```
Cellphones
PK_ID | PERSON_ID | NUMBER
1 | 1 | +81037101
2 | 1 | +81911132
3 | 2 | +6182928191
```

Let's say we want to join the result and obtain all the information about our clients. How will I parse the information in java giving I have a class Person which has an ArrayList?
How could I parse all the numbers that Tim has if I have a multiple row result from the inner join? What is the best way to parse the cellphones of all the "Persons"? SQL-Logic with group_concat, then a split in java, or SQL pure row fetch then parsing them in java? Which is better as performance?

Comment: JDBC or Hibernate typically return a collection of records, either as a `List<Object>` or a collection of entities.  It is up to you to sort this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, to be able to load all the phone numbers of Tim using one query, i recommend you to use Hibernate Framework, Create and annotate you entities, and with a simple JPQL query you can retrieve all tha data for a given person without taking too much care about the query and how to store the data into you entites.
Also I recommend Hibernate for a better performance.
Good luck

Comment: I have never used hibernate, could you recommend a good website with examples / tutorials for this framework?

Comment: a good one, hope it helps you

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/

Comment: Thank you, I already started learning from there. Easy to understand.